# How to set different destination ('region') of an aws cloudwatch logging agent inside a docker image?

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM 796678920264.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myproject/base:latest

COPY /* /


RUN python awslogs-agent-setup.py --non-interactive -c /aws-log.myservice.cfg --region us-west-2


CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

I use the dockerfile to build images that will be used in both dev and production environment. The behaviour is determined by an env variable. i.e. I will do something like this to start a docker container: `docker run -e ENV=dev -ti myservice`

One issue with this dockerfile is that: the logs in both dev and prod are sent to the same cloudwatch log in the region `us-west-2`.

Is there anything I can do to change the region for dev  environment to a different value when a docker container is started? Preferably it should be controlled by the same environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add and call the following script in the main CMD script

```
if [ "$ENV"  != "prod" ]; then
    AWSLOG_CONF=/var/awslogs/etc/aws.conf
    sed -i -e 's/region = us-west-2/region = ap-southeast-1/g' $AWSLOG_CONF
    echo 'Set the awslog region to ap-southeast-1'
fi
```

The script must be called before the aws log service is started.

Comment: For anyone who installed awslogs via yum on amazon linux, region was set in /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf. Change it there as it was set to us-east-1 by default.